# Predicate logic, translate sentence

Tags: logic, logic-translation

I need help with how to translate a sentence into predicate logic. It would also be nice if you could have a look at another one that I have solved, if it is correctly solved

- *Given predicates:*
- Empty(x) : the list x is empty
- Sorted(x) : the list x is sorted in ascending (not decreasing) order
- x < y : number x is smaller than number y
- At(x, i, y) : the list x contains the number y on position i

The start position begins always at zero in a list.

The sentence: **If a list is empty, then there are no numbers on any position in the list.**

What I have tried: ∃x(Empty(x)->∀y(At(x, i, y) ?????))

Another sentence that I think I have solved correctly:

Sentence: **All the numbers in the list L is greater than 100**

My answer: ∀x(At(L, i, x)->100 < x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sentence: **If a list is empty, then there are no numbers on any position in the list.**
>
> What I have tried: ∃x(Empty(x)->∀y(At(x, i, y) ?????))

You just said, "There exists one list such if it is empty it follows that *all* numbers exist at position i." !?

(You also did not quantify the position.  Is it universal or existential?)

What you want is more:
$$\forall x:\Bigl(\mathsf{Empty}(x) \to \neg\bigl(\exists y\,\exists i :\mathsf{At}(x, i, y)\bigr)\Bigr)$$

---

> Sentence: **All the numbers in the list L is greater than 100**
>
> My answer: ∀x(At(L, i, x)->100 < x)

That could almost work but, again, you haven't quantified the list index (i).

Also, purely as a matter of style, I suggest you don't mix the types of your entities.   If you discuss $x$ as list and $y$ as a number in one part of the discussion, don't switch to using $x$ for numbers.   It's not technically wrong, *per se*, but it is mildly confusing.   Avoid that by using the same symbol to refer to entities of same type of things (as much as possible).

$$\forall y:\Bigl(\bigl(\exists i:\mathsf{At}(L,i,y)\bigr)\to 100<y\Bigr)$$

Comment: **(You also did not quantify the position. Is it universal or existential?)**

How do I know? This is the whole text from my book:

**In this task, you should express some facts about the data structure "lists of positive integers." An example of such a list is [41, 19, 7, 5, 2, 5], ie, the number 41 is at position 0 in the list, number 19 is at position 1, and so on.**


I'm really thankful for your help.

Comment: I think it should be existential, because there is at least one position for every number. not many positions for every number.